# How to call Web API in Console Application using Query string Param

Tags: c#, console-application

I have parameter's In my Query string so I need to pass like below given URL:

```
URL + ?dd={{Some Json Data}}&accessKey=ddfr54r5g5r

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
string url = "URL + ?dd={{Some Json Data}}&accessKey=ddfr54r5g5r";
var jsonData = webClient.DownloadData(url);
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
RootObject obj = new RootObject();
obj = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(jsonData));
```

Can anyone share some method which will be working for your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `URL` is a variable then why you are stringifying it. It should be like

```
string url = URL + "?dd={{Some Json Data}}&accessKey=ddfr54r5g5r";
```

Again no need of instantiating a `DataContractJsonSerializer` for desrializing the data. Rather use `Newtonsoft.Json` and call the `DeserializeObject()` method like `var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);`

I would suggest to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class rather which gives more control. Something like

```
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
   {
      try   
      {
         string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
         var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBody);         
      }  
      catch(HttpRequestException e)
      {
          //log exception
      }
   }
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client to get more idea on this

Comment: It's Showing Method Not Allowed          string apiUrl = URL + "?payload=" + json + "&accessKey=4b72c9f6-9393-475b-9c72-72ab40a4d9b9";       HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, null).Result;
                                    var rest = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                                    APIResponseObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponseObject>(rest);

Comment: This Error I will be Getting :   {StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

Comment: @RomilShah for a post operation pass the data as message body and not though url

Comment: this is the HTTPGET Operation & Which API I Have is a 3 rd Party API They passed all values in Query string only not Body or Header.... Do you have Any idea ?? Using Query string